# Browser not rendering css and JS

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, php-fpm

I'm using:

- CentOS 7
- Apache 2.4
- php56-php-fpm
- php72-php-fpm

on my dev server. I managed to get it so I can specify a handler and it will put that vhost on the correct PHP version, however CSS and JS seem to be going awry.

I get this error:

> scriptname.js was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type

which eventually leads to fatal error's. Googling it led me to various posts and I added the below first to my `httpd.conf` file:

```
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js
```

But that didn't work.

I then added it to my .htaccess, again with no success.

I then found something that suggested writing it like this:

```
AddType 'text/css; charset=UTF-8' .css
```

This did fix the CSS for the most part - but not the `.js`.

How do I get it so everything works as expected?

(note: let me know which file contents to add and I'll edit question accordingly)

## EDIT:

I've got the error messages down to:

> Loading failed for the  with source /path/to/file.js

By adding this to my vhost file:

```
<Files *.js
  Header set Content-type "text/javascript"
</Files>
```

Seems going to that file shows:

> Access Denied

file permissions for there:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 dev-admin dev-admin    42 Apr  4 11:37 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 dev-admin dev-admin    27 Mar 12 17:21 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 dev-admin dev-admin 86927 Mar  1 15:14 jquery.min.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 dev-admin dev-admin  5094 Apr  4 11:37 main.js
```

Headers on file:

[image]

full vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.development
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dev/site1
    <Directory /var/www/dev/site1>
        # removing this shows the MIME type errors from before
        <Files *.css>
            Header set Content-type "text/css"
        </Files>
        # removing this shows the MIME type errors from before
        <Files *.js>
            Header set Content-type "text/javascript"
        </Files>

        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9072"

        AllowOverride all
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I see the problem. Your `SetHandler` is applying to every possible URL in the virtual host, without regard for whether it is a PHP file or not. Thus everything gets passed to PHP, even if it is a static file. And because PHP's interpreting the static file as PHP, you get the results you got.

You should instead send only requests for PHP files to the handler, by selecting them by filename:

```
        <FilesMatch \.php$>
            SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9072"
        </FilesMatch>
```

You can then remove the unnecessary redundant `<Files>` bits that you had added.

Comment: P.S. You should also not disable SELinux, but that's another series of questions...

Comment: you chicken legend! Worked :)

Answer (score 1):

The 403 error usually comes from a permission error.  It could either be at the directory or the files level.

In your case, from what I can see (only the file and the apache doc root directory permissions), permissions seems fine.

Could you share with us the parents directories permissions?  (it could be the /var/www/dev/ that have too restrictive permissions)

If the permissions aren't allowing "other", 0755 should do it...

```
chmod 0755 /var/www/dev
```

Also, /var/www/dev should belong to "dev-admin".  If that isn't the case, I would suggest to change the ownership of it:

```
chown dev-admin: /var/www/dev
```

And @Michael Hampton is right.  None of your changes were required (on a default CentOS 7 Apache configuration).

Ohh!  Just to make sure that we are covering all the bases...  Does dev-admin is the Apache user?

If not, you may either change it within the main Apache configuration or by changing the dev directory (recursive) with the proper user.

Comment: if you saw the file permissions - they're already 644 on files and 755 on dir's and dev-admin is the owner ...